# Equivalent of /mfx in SQL Compare 12?

Tags: sql-server, redgate, sqlcompare

In previous versions of Redgate's SQL Compare it was possible to pass in a command-line parameter with the location of the migrations scripts folder thus:

```
sqlcompare /mfx $migrationScriptsFolder
```

However, in the latest version of SQL Compare (12) this switch is no longer available (yet `/sfx` to indicate the location of the scripts folder is still available).

Is there an alternative way of setting this value in SQL Compare 12? The command line reference for the new version does not address migration scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the devs on SQL Compare at the moment.

SQL Compare 12 is designed to work with SQL Source Control 5 migrations, where the migration details are stored in the same folder as the rest of the database schema rather than needing separate script and migrations folders. This means the equivalent in v12 is to just use the `/sfx` switch to point to this one folder.

Hope that helps :)